# When does Marty Travel to in the future?

Tags: back-to-the-future, back-to-the-future-ii

I have seen all sorts of posts on the Internet about when he travels to, but most of them are doctored to make people repost them.  I originally saw one picture that showed the deLorean dash showing a date in 2012, like this one.

[image: Time circuits showing a date in 2012]

This could be an original shot from the movie before the panel was tampered with
[image: Could be original]

So what is the real date he traveled to?

Comment: You may find this useful... http://www.istodaybacktothefutureday.com/

Comment: LOL I like that one.  there is another site I found while searching. http://www.october212015.com/

Comment: Where did you pull such low-quality images? 9gag? And on the first image, is the `J` bending in the corner?

Comment: lol, I just did a Google Search @IsmaelMiguel

Comment: Also relevant: http://martymcflyinthefuture.tumblr.com/

Comment: That is all too funny, @ArturoTorresSánchez!

Comment: I like how "2012" in the last screenshot doesn't even match the LCD screen

Comment: lol I just noticed that myself...lol.  on the actual panel it is difficult to read the panels. I am guessing here but I think that these aren't LCD or LED boards but actually incandescent displays.

Comment: @Moyli, if you look closely at the `J` the hook of it doesn't take up an entire light either, on both `JUN` and `JAN`

Comment: The "2012" and "2014" in these pictures are dead giveaways. Look at the close spacing between the "0" and the "1". 7-segment displays can't do that - look at the "01" in the time readouts, or the "2015" in the actual movie (photo in Malachi's answer below). The displays were indeed 7-segment LED readout modules except for the months - those were faked with something like a litho negative and colored lights behind them. The photo linked by Malachi clearly shows dark segments in the digit displays but not in the alpha displays.

Comment: He arrives today!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

## October 21, 2015 4:29 PM

Snopes had this to say

> All of these japes are easy to identify as hoaxes by simply remembering the number 30: The original Back to the Future Part film was set (and released) in 1985, and in that film Marty McFly traveled thirty years back in time, to 1955. In the sequel, Back to the Future Part II, Marty traveled thirty years forward in time, from 1985 to 2015. The latter is therefore the year Marty will "return" — not 2012 or 2013 or 2014, but 2015. The date of 21 October 2015, to be precise:
> Read more at http://www.snopes.com/inboxer/hoaxes/bttf.asp#wb6jI6D7iAwzE097.99

Precisely at 4:29 PM Wednesday October 21st, 2015

[image: Original Screenshot from the movie]

---

The Second image in the question is another Photoshop spoof and not from the movie and is mentioned in the Snopes article above.

Comment: The scientists have a lot of work to do in 22 days.

Comment: They just need to capture The DeLorean and then figure it out! it should run on Garbage, right?  I think I need to watch these movies again!  lol

Comment: Precisely at 4:29 PM _**PDT**_ Wednesday October 21st, 2015

Comment: @RogueJedi. Not as much as Hollywood; they have alot of Jaws films to make ASAP.

Comment: @kaine Or just one with a misleading name.

Comment: @RogueJedi Turns out Doc and Marty didn't travel to 2015 Hill Valley, they travelled to 2015 Hollywood on the set of the remake of BTTF2...