# What time did Marty arrive in Nov 5th 1955?

Tags: back-to-the-future

What time was on the ‘destination time’ when Marty travels to 1955. I can see it’s Nov 5th 1955 and then the hour is 06 but you don’t see what minutes?

Have looked online and seen a few different times on replica models/posters but need to know the exact time.

Comment: The [Fandom site for BttF](https://backtothefuture.fandom.com/wiki/Back_to_the_Future_timeline) claims Marty arrives at 6:15 a.m, however, they don't mention their source for this time.

Answer (score 1):

The photo below is a screen shot of Marty and the Delorean screaming away from the Peabody Farm.  As you can see, the skyline is showing the first blush of dawn's early light.
[image]

As shown in the rough wild west map of *Back to the Future III*, Hill Valley is in Northern California.  According to sunrise times for November 5th, that makes it about 6:39 AM.  I'm not sure how that fandom site is 24 minutes off.  Ah, well.

Comment: Related question: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/105102/where-is-hill-valley

Comment: Maybe it's on a mountain that's much higher than everything in the east, so sunset is earlier. I know the picture makes it look like there are taller mountains in the east, which obviously means the cameras tilted.